# Layout Span - table layout android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, columnspan

I'm using tableLayout (android) to create tables with 5 columns 
I need to span column inside table , but can't using  **layout-span** correctly to become table like this :

`|column  1 | column 2 | column 3 | column  4 | column 5  |
 |column 11 |          column 22              | column 33 |`

my code :

```
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="column  1"
                android:id="@+id/q5"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/s" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="column  2"
                android:id="@+id/q4"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/s" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="column  3"
                android:id="@+id/q3"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/s" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="column  4"
                android:id="@+id/q2"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/s" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="column  5"
                android:id="@+id/q1"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/s" />
        </TableRow>





        <TableRow>

           <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="column  11"
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/s" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="column  22"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/s" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="column  33"
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/s" />


        </TableRow>
```

a problem is : column 11 and column 33 is change width so a layout design is bad .. please help me what can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.sanjaysah.tablelayout.MainActivity">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@drawable/row_background"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="column 1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@drawable/row_background"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="column 2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@drawable/row_background"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="column 3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@drawable/row_background"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="column 4"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@drawable/row_background"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="column 5"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@drawable/row_background"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="column 11"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_span="3"
            android:background="@drawable/row_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="column 22"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@drawable/row_background"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="column 33"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

This will render a tablelayout that you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you .. it's work , but I need first and last column for second row  has same width like fist and last column for  first row ! .. thanks again

Comment: If my answer solved your issue then please accept the answer.